# Retrofit takes too much time to get response

Tags: java, android, rest, api, retrofit2

I'm using retrofit for REST API call. When checking using **POSTMAN client** the **response i can get it in fraction of seconds**. I takes less than a second to get response. While i **called the request using the retrofit** it **takes more than 5 to 10 seconds to get the response**. It shows my app working slower. Kindly suggest me a solution.

Note: Web API created in .NET

Below is my code

```
//Retrofit client code:

HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new 
            OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor)
                                .connectTimeout(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .readTimeout(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .build();


    if (client != null) {
        ConnectionPool pool = client.connectionPool();
        if (pool != null) {

            pool.evictAll();
        }
    }

    if (retrofit==null) {
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }
```

And my request call is below:

```
 private void makeServiceCallUPSData(String upsNameId, String spvId) {
    showLoadingView();

    if (calledFrom.equals(Constants.UPS_EDIT)) {
        logId = upsId;
    } else {
        logId = "0";
    }

    apiService.getUPSData(upsNameId, spvId, logId, authorizationToken).enqueue(new Callback<UPSDataResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<UPSDataResponse> call, Response<UPSDataResponse> response) {

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                UPSDataResponse upsDataResponse = response.body();
                hideLoadingView();
                if (upsDataResponse.getCode() == Constants.RESPONSE_SUCCESS) {
                    updateUI(upsDataResponse);
                } else {
                    showErrorAlertDialog(upsDataResponse.getMessage());
                }
                Logger.infoLog("Logg resp " + response.body());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<UPSDataResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            //dismissProgressDialog();
            hideLoadingView();
            //Toast.makeText(thisActivity, "Server not Responsding. Try after Sometime", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Also added the below the log:

```
 07-19 16:57:07.920 32345-2045/com.vcarel.test D/OkHttp: --> GET http://14.143.142.43/api/HMS/HMSUPS/GetUPSData?upsNameId=2370&spvId=6&logId=0
 07-19 16:57:07.920 32345-2045/com.vcarel.test D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: max-age=640000
 07-19 16:57:07.920 32345-2045/com.vcarel.test D/OkHttp: Authorization: bearer 6ndJHgICCPj6zaMpW6SzEZN06zcDHE5PaEHVJ9jol--Md5Hla_J-Nx9-wynQ_nG8OBjNn5LjA5
 07-19 16:57:07.920 32345-2045/com.vcarel.test D/OkHttp: --> END GET
 07-19 16:57:12.670 32345-2045/com.vcarel.test D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://14.143.142.43/api/HMS/HMSUPS/GetUPSData?upsNameId=2370&spvId=6&logId=0 (4747ms)
 07-19 16:57:12.670 32345-2045/com.vcarel.test D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache
 07-19 16:57:12.670 32345-2045/com.vcarel.test D/OkHttp: Pragma: no-cache
 07-19 16:57:12.670 32345-2045/com.vcarel.test D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
 07-19 16:57:12.670 32345-2045/com.vcarel.test D/OkHttp: Expires: -1
 07-19 16:57:12.670 32345-2045/com.vcarel.test D/OkHttp: Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
 07-19 16:57:12.670 32345-2045/com.vcarel.test D/OkHttp: X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
 07-19 16:57:12.670 32345-2045/com.vcarel.test D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
 07-19 16:57:12.670 32345-2045/com.vcarel.test D/OkHttp: Date: Thu, 19 Jul 2018 11:27:23 GMT
 07-19 16:57:12.670 32345-2045/com.vcarel.test D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 513
 07-19 16:57:12.670 32345-2045/com.vcarel.test D/OkHttp: {"Code":200,"Message":"Success","Respone":{"MainCurrentB":"1.000","MainCurrentR":"1.000","MainCurrentY":"1.000","MainVoltageB":"1.000","MainVoltageR":"1.000","MainVoltageY":"1.000","MainRectifierVoltage":"2.500","BypassVoltage":"1.000","BypassCurrent":"2.500","BypassFr48to52Hz":"0.000","OutputVoltage":"2.225","OutputCurrent":"2.500","OutputFr48to52Hz":"0.000","OutputTem":"2.500","BatteryVdc":"25.000","BatteryLb":"0.000","DateTime":"2018-07-19 16:42:00","Remarks":"test","fromVDC":"300.000","toVDC":"350.000"}}
 07-19 16:57:12.670 32345-2045/com.vcarel.test D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (513-byte body)
```

In the above log see the time difference between **End GET** and **200 OK** Likewise i'm getting delay it resembles app being working slower.

Comment: @pskink can't get you?

Comment: Yes, i checked in Log its getting delay to receive the response

Comment: Did you find the solution ? I'm facing similar issue here

Answer (score 0):

from response fill recyclerview,listview or any other more fiels fill at once in your  updateUI(upsDataResponse) method

Comment: no i'm telling before binding it to UI checked in Log itself. There it taking to much time to get the response from server